# why does ternary statement produce correct result

Tags: javascript, time, ternary

I have the following function.  Since hours = hours will always be true why does this return 12 when hours = 0?

```js
function timeFormat(date) {

  date.replaceAll("-","/"); 
  date = new Date(date + " edt"); 
  
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  
  hours = hours % 12; 
  console.log(hours)
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  
  
  
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+ minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

console.log(timeFormat("2022-05-6 12:00:00"))
```

Comment: `0` is a falsey value, so it evaluates to false, therefore 12 is returned; I don't understand your point when you say "*hours = hours will always be true.*" The assignment will evaluate to true, sure, but that's not being tested/assessed anywhere.

Comment: `hours=hours` will return exactly the same as `hours`: a falsy value for `hours===0` and a truthy value for anything else.